# Error when parsing XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): **http://goo.gl/GZXZqb**:2: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in /home/XXX on line 138

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): <b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in <b>/home/vhosts/XXX/web/c in /home/XXX on line 138

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in /home/mXXX on line 138
```

If I save the file on my server, it works (save as xxx.xml)

PHP code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://goo.gl/GZXZqb','SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

Comment: what is on line 138?

Comment: try to explain a lot,.. it'll be easy to clear your issue

Comment: this is the erorr 
and the code i have is just $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://goo.gl/GZXZqb','SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);

Comment: I got a header error from the link: http://www.emalon.co.il/mobile-export?type=hotels-list

Comment: So ,The problem is on the remote side? @ClydeWinux